# How to input SWRL-rule with negation in SWRLtab in Protege 5?

Tags: ontology, protege, swrl

[Here](https://github.com/protegeproject/swrlapi/wiki/SWRLLanguageFAQ) I have found that it should be possible to write a SWRL-rule like this:

`Person(?p) ^ (hasCar = 0)(?p) -> CarlessPerson(?p)`

But when I have tried to input this example in SWRLtab in Protege I got an error: Unexpected character '='

I tried to input it in another way:

`Person(?p) ^ (hasCar max 0 Car)(?p) -> CarlessPerson(?p)`

but it also doesn't work.

How to input such rules in SWRLtab in Protege?

Comment: From https://github.com/protegeproject/swrlapi/wiki/SWRLAPISWRLSyntax#how-are-swrl-class-atoms-represented: *The SWRL Submission also allows arbitrary OWL expressions to be used instead of a class name in class atoms. The SWRL Editor does not currently support use of these expressions.*

Comment: also asked on the Protege mailing list, got an answer there. Clearly, 1) syntax issue + 2) Open world Assumption would not allow this inference anyways